# Regex match SQL values string with multiple rows and same number of columns

Tags: sql, regex

I tried to match the sql values string `(0),(5),(12),...` or `(0,11),(122,33),(4,51),...` or `(0,121,12),(31,4,5),(26,227,38),...` and so on with the regular expression

```
\(\s*\d+\s*(\s*,\s*\d+\s*)*\)(\s*,\s*\(\s*\d+\s*(\s*,\s*\d+\s*)*\))*
```

and it works. But...

How can I ensure that the regex does not match a values string like `(0,12),(1,2,3),(56,7)` with different number of columns?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please, provide more details about you issue. As far i understand that you want to be sure that the count of numbers between brackets is the same. Am i right? What database engine? Do you want to use clear SQL?

Comment: I use MS SQL Server 2008. And you're right. The count of numbers between the brackets must be the same.

Comment: The question about clear sql is still active... Could it be client side code (C# + Linq)?

Comment: I hope it's possible to solve this problem without any algorithm, only with a regular expression.

Comment: @MichSch, in my opinion it's impossible to use only Regex.

Answer (score 2):

As i mentioned in comment to the question, the best way to check if input string is valid: contains the same count of numbers between brackets, is to use client side programm, but not clear SQL.

Implementation:

```
List<string> s = new List<string>(){
    "(0),(5),(12)", "(0,11),(122,33),(4,51)",
    "(0,121,12),(31,4,5),(26,227,38)","(0,12),(1,2,3),(56,7)"};

var qry = s.Select(a=>new
    {
         orig = a,
         newst = a.Split(new string[]{"),(", "(", ")"},
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    })
        .Select(a=>new
    {
         orig = a.orig,
         isValid = (a.newst
             .Sum(b=>b.Split(new char[]{','},
                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count()) %
                 a.newst.Count()) ==0
    });
```

Result:

```
orig                            isValid
(0),(5),(12)                    True 
(0,11),(122,33),(4,51)          True 
(0,121,12),(31,4,5),(26,227,38) True 
(0,12),(1,2,3),(56,7)           False
```

Note: The second `Select` statement gets the modulo of sum of comma instances and the count of items in string array returned by `Split` function. If the result isn't equal to zero, it means that input string is invalid.

I strongly believe there's a simplest way to achieve that, but - at this moment - i don't know how ;)

Answer (score 1):

:(

Unless you add some more constraints, I don't think you can solve this problem only with regular expressions.

It isn't able to solve all of your string problems, just as it cannot be used to check that the opening and closing of brackets (like "((())()(()(())))") is invalid. That's a more complicated issue.

That's what I learnt in class :P If someone knows a way then that'd be sweet!

I'm sorry, I spent a bit of time looking into how we could turn this string into an array and do more work to it with SQL but built in functionality is lacking and the solution would end up being very hacky.

I'd recommend trying to handle this situation differently as large scale string computation isn't the best way to go if your database is to gradually fill up.

A combination of client and serverside validation can be used to help prevent bad data (like the ones with more numbers) from getting into the database.

If you need to keep those numbers then you could rework your schema to include some metadata which you can use in your queries, like how many numbers there are and whether it all matches nicely. This information can be computed inexpensively from your server and provided to the database.

Good luck!

Comment: I forgot to enclose the regex as <pre> block. Now the opening and closing of brackets should be correct.